# How to get rid of this whitespace in internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, graphics, components

I've got a Facebook like button that is bugging me in internet explorer 7/8 (this doesn't happen in Firefox or Google Chrome or IE9(+))
[image]

I want to get rid of the white area but how? The relevant HTML and CSS is

```
<div class="fbstuff">  
    <div style="margin-top:3px;margin-left:15px;float:right;">         
        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.phphref=http://www.bnano.eu&amp;layout=button_count&amp;locale=en_US" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; width:200px; height:80px"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why the white area appears and this seems to happen in =< IE8 only. What can I do to resolve this? [Here's](http://bnano.eu) the live link. Thanks.

Comment: padding: 0; margin: 0; ?

Comment: u seem to use width to set right margin? Why not use margin-right and skip width/height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting the width and height in the html of your iframe here:

```
width:200px; height:80px
```

if you delete these values, your browser will render the default size for an iframe. Rather set these values to exaclty the dimensions of the button.

the reason why you see it in IE and not in firefox, is that firefox renders an iframe background as transparent and old IE renders it as white

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the width and height to 200x80:

```
width:200px; height:80px
```

Delete this code.